# List as an argument in class?

Tags: python

How do we pass a list as an argument of a python class?

```
class My_Class:
    def __init__(self, att, mylist[]):
        self.att=att
        self.mylist = mylist[]
```

Comment: what have you tried? did it work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters

Comment: Just get rid of all the `[]`…!?

Comment: You just pass it - there's no special syntax...

Comment: You can leave off the square brackets `[]` in both your parameter list and the assignment statement.  As long as the *type* of `mylist` is a list, it will be treated as a list.

Comment: @DatHydroGuy `s/can/must/`

Comment: On the off-chance that you are asking about type hinting, it would be `def __init__(self, att, mylist: List[Any])` (assuming you have imported the names `List` and `Any` from the `typing` module).

Comment: Side note: Please don't name your classes like `My_Class`. That looks like [Wordpress class naming conventions](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/#naming-conventions) which are, IMO, some of the objectively worst conventions on the planet. But we can avoid the "IMO" part here since Python has an [official style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)! Following PEP 8, you might name your class `MyClass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify that it is a list. Python is a dynamically and strongly typed language.

```
class My_Class:
    def __init__(self, att, mylist):
        self.att = att
        self.mylist = mylist
```

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing to it, really. In Python we do not need to declare the type of parameters:

```
class My_Class:
    def __init__(self, att, mylist):
        self.att = att
        self.mylist = mylist
```

Comment: The how do I print the list? print(instance.mylist)?

Comment: @Azazel, why would you think you should use `instance`? It looks like you would benefit from a Python tutorial. Start with the basics, which will cover things like variable names and types (so you won't make mistakes like `mylist[]`), then look for one that deals with object-oriented Python code.

Comment: by instance I meant instance of that My_Class.....something like: class1=My_Class('ABC', ['123','456','789'])

Answer (score 0):

You simply pass a reference to the list

```
class My_Class:
def __init__( self, att, mylist ):
    self.att=att
    self.mylist = mylist
```